# Scroll and zooming does not work simultaneously in MpChart android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mpchart

I've implemented a line chart from mp chart android but the thing is there are two buttons full view and a yearly view, in full view, I'm setting zoom to x 0,y 0. but in yearly view, I am zooming in the graph. this is working fine
but the problem is when I scroll the graph and press the button full view while the graph is scrolling zooming out does not work. but when the graph scrolls idle both yearly and full-view functionalities are working fine.

```
private void changeSelectionOfView(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                txvFullView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.Pennyworthgray1));
                txvYearly.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.white));
                lineChart.zoom(10f, 1, hightligh.getX(), hightligh.getY(), YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
                llYearly.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.primary_btnn_shape_app_generic_selected));
                llFullView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.white));
                if (popupWindow != null && popupWindow.isShowing()) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                txvFullView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.white));
                txvYearly.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.Pennyworthgray1));
                llFullView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.primary_btnn_shape_app_generic_selected));
                llYearly.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.white));
                lineChart.fitScreen();
//              lineChart.zoomToCenter(0, 0);
                if (popupWindow != null && popupWindow.isShowing()) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
                break;
        }
        lineChart.invalidate();
}
```

this is the code i'm using case 1 is for yearly view and case 2 is for full view. i've tried fit screen but it does not work either.